# The location of received email in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, exim

I installed exim4 on my debian machine. And I've successfully send an email to my Gmail address. But when I send an email from my Gmail to my linux machine. I dont know how can I read it and where is the location of this email.

Answer (score 1):

By default all e-mail goes to /var/spool/mail/$USERNAME

where $USERNAME is the username you're using.

If you don't have a mail reader installed, you can try to use

mailx

at a terminal but it's interface is hard to use (basically p, n, and other keystrokes) for begginers. Another, better option to be used at a terminal is

mutt

Cheers